# Unable to add conditional first entry to selectlist drop-down menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

The project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5

I seem to be utterly unable to add a first entry to a selectlist in a conditional manner.

Below is my code:

```
public SelectList getStatus(Guid company) {
  var statusValue = db.Company.Where(x => x.CompanyId.Equals(company)).Select(x => new { CompanyStatusId = x.CompanyStatusId }).SingleOrDefault();
  var statusList = db.CompanyStatus.Select(x => new { CompanyStatusId = x.CompanyStatusId, CompanyStatusName = x.CompanyStatusName }).ToList();
  var status = new SelectList(statusList, "CompanyStatusId", "CompanyStatusName", statusValue);
  if(statusValue.CompanyStatusId.Equals(Guid.Empty) || statusValue.CompanyStatusId.Equals(null)) {
    var insertItem = new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = " « ‹ Select a Status › » " };
    status.ToList().Add(insertItem);
  }
  return status;
}
```

Walkthrough via line number, within the method:

1. Get CompanyStatusId from the Company table. This is a foreign key to
   a lookup table.
2. Get the lookup table that provides the foreign key.
3. IF statement: if the CompanyStatusId is null or blank or is an empty
   Guid, add an initial "choose status" entry with a blank value.

The reason why I want this is so that any company that already has a status will not get the "choose status" entry, but any company that doesn't does get the entry. However, what I have above DOES NOT WORK. I have confirmed via breakpoints that a null value for the Guid does indeed trigger the If statement (so that works at least) and that the contents of the IF statement do get processed, but the resulting drop-down menu does not have the "choose status" entry.

This is all sitting in a BaseController since it needs to be accessible from a large swath of internal pages. The drop-down list on the front end is populated by a ViewBag from this BaseController.

Help?

Comment: `status.ToList()` is creating a new `List<SelectListItem>` (and you adding the new item to that, not the `SelectList`)

Comment: I have no clue how to correct this. It is why I asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status.ToList().Add(insertItem);` is first generating a new `List<SelectListItem>` and adding `insertItem` to it. It is not altering the original `SelectList`. To make this work, change the method to

```
public List<SelectListItem> getStatus(Guid company) // change signature
{
    var statusValue = db.Company.Where(x => x.CompanyId.Equals(company)).Select(x => new { CompanyStatusId = x.CompanyStatusId }).SingleOrDefault();
    var statusList = db.CompanyStatus.Select(x => new { CompanyStatusId = x.CompanyStatusId, CompanyStatusName = x.CompanyStatusName }).ToList();
    var status = new SelectList(statusList, "CompanyStatusId", "CompanyStatusName", statusValue).ToList(); // change
    if(statusValue.CompanyStatusId.Equals(Guid.Empty) || statusValue.CompanyStatusId.Equals(null))
    {
        var insertItem = new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = " « ‹ Select a Status › » " };
        status.Add(insertItem); // change
    }
    return status;
}
```

Side note: typically the "Select a Status" option would be the first option, in which case you would need to use `status.Insert(0, insertItem);`

Note also that there is no point adding the last parameter in the `SelectList` constructor (i.e. `statusValue`) if your binding to a model property (its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method.

Comment: Okay, this… worked. Technically. So the "select status" is now in the list, but not only is it at the very end of the list (so it doesn't show as the first and default-visible value when no item has the selected value), but on those companies for whom a status has been shown, it is no longer being selected as the default option. Hmmm...

Comment: AHA! Changing it to `status.Insert(0, insertItem);` worked!

Comment: And just so you know, I am not using `DropDownListFor`, I am just using `DropDownList` as I am utilizing a `ViewBag` and not a model.

Comment: Cringe. You should always use the strongly typed `xxxxFor()` methods and preferably always use a view model.

Comment: Solved the problem. My `statusValue` was needlessly complex. I change the incoming Guid name from `company` to `id` and then swapped the `statusValue` line with `Company company = db.Company.Find(id);`. I then changed every instance of `statusValue` with `company.CompanyStatusId` and things began to work properly. Now if a Status Id is set, the drop-down menu has the correct item selected. As for your strongly typed argument, do you happen to have a link to a good explanation why vs ViewBags?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I don’t think I would have been able to figure out the primary issue by myself.